# Visual Studio 2012 Lightswitch "Unable to connect to server" in Desktop app

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm getting the following screen after I successfully publish the application.
The error message says "The application has stopped responding due to an error and needs to be restarted.
Error details: Unable to connect to server.  Please contact a network administrator.
"

How can I debug this? Or Does anyone know what could be going on?

[image]